# How to convert PDF file pages to jpg image using imagemagick in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I'm searching for converting each page of the PDF to JPEG.

I found the below code from the following link:
http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/discussions/257915

here are two ways to convert a pdf to an image. You can either read all the images at once or just read one image. For this to work you need to have ghostscript installed.

```
using (ImageList imageList = new ImageList())
{
    imageList.ReadImages(inputFile);
    int pageIndex = 0;
    foreach (Image page in imageList)
    {
        page.Write(outputDirectory + "\\Page." + pageIndex + ".jpg");
        pageIndex++;
    }
}

using (Image firstPage = new Image())
{
    firstPage.Read(inputFile + "[0]");
    firstPage.Write(outputDirectory + "\\FirstPage.jpg");
}
```

Here the imagelist class is not recognizing. I have added the DLL. Do u have any worked samples?Also Ghostscript download is an EXE file but not DLL?

Comment: I am also trying to work this out myself, however GhostScript is an exe but after you install it, do get to the install folder and grab the dll file. Try to use the 32bit version (I have read about problems with 64 bit). The file you are looking for is 'gs32dll.dll' after instalation

Comment: I use аpitron pdf rasterizer for that